# Show inventory of simple product in Magento

Tags: php, magento, inventory

I want to show stock qty on the checkout page. But when more than 15 in stock then show 15+.

I have the configurable product fix but the simple don't work.

```
<?php } elseif($custom->getTypeId() == 'configurable' ) {  ?>

        <?php

        $children = $custom->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
        $totaal = count($children);
        $i = 0;
        $childStockQty = 0;
            if ($totaal > 0) {
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $i++;
                    $childStock = $child->getStockItem();
                    $childStockQty = $childStock->getQty();
                    $childStockPid = $childStock->getProductId();
                    $childStockQty_tot = $childStockQty_tot + $childStockQty; 

                    echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child->getEntityId())->getAttributeText('kleur');

                    if($childStockQty > 15)
                    {
                        echo ': 15+';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo ': ' . round($childStockQty, 0);
                    }
                    if($i != $totaal)
                    {
                        echo '</br>';
                    }
                }
                //echo $childStockQty_tot;
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: What is your question. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your code is wrapped in

```
elseif($custom->getTypeId() == 'configurable' )
```

So it effectively only show for configurable product, which make senses because you are calling getUsedProducts() which is not available in simple product.
I think you will need something like:

```
if ($custom->getTypeId() === 'simple') {
    $quantity = $custom->getStockItem()->getQty();
    if ($quantity >= 15) {
    } else ...
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

When i edit file /template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml, with the code getTypeId() == 'simple' ) {//echo $_item->getProductId();$quantity = $custom->getStockItem()->getQty();if ($quantity >= 15){echo ': 15+';}
else{echo ': ' . round($quantity, 0);} if($i != $totaal){echo '';}?>

Than see you the 15+ only on the wrong place. 
https://www.weddingdeco.nl/checkout/cart/#